# USB flash drive recognised by dmesg&lsusb but not as device in /dev/sd*

Tags: mount, usb-drive

If I connect the usb drive to my maschine I can see, that it is indeed connected, yet I can't find the device in /dev/sd*

The following is shown in dmesg (lsusb also sees the device):

```
usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 0.02
usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-2: Product: Intenso Ultra Line  
usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ALCOR          
usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 88F8544B
usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host4: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
```

I would like to restore the data on the device. Is there any way of mounting it to get a backup?

Comment: There should be a few more lines in `dmesg` identifying what device the usb drive is identified as. Failing that, does `lsscsi -d` give any useful information?

Comment: `dmesg` shows no more information than what i already posted. `lsscsi` only outputs my hard drive, and nothing about the flash drive

Comment: So it's apparently a hardware fault, which I can't really do anything about. Maybe the flash chip is broken while the usb controller is still in takt.